# HTML Canvas Style Options

Tags: html, css, canvas

I was reading [this](http://blog.sklambert.com/html5-canvas-game-panning-a-background/) guide to HTML5 games, and was curious about how the canvas is styled.

His code is:

```
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

I'm wondering where I can find more info about these attributes (`position`, `top`, `left`, `background`).

Comment: Yeah, I tried googling this before I posted and didn't find much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called absolute [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) in CSS.

The `top` and `left` means to position it relative to its nearest positioned container (generally the document's `body`).

The `background: transparent` is not required as it's the default value for elements.

It's probably used to have the `canvas` element be positioned in the top left hand corner of the document.